# Upload e arquivos utilizando API Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou criando um end-point para upar um arquivo no formato (.txt) , porém minha entidade não se consiste apenas no arquivo. Existem outros atributos, desta forma eu preciso enviar um json desta forma para o servidor :

```
{
"nomeCliente" : "teste", 
"arquivo": // aqui eu enviaria o arquivo.
}
```

Porém desta forma o arquivo não chega o servidor. Estou utilizando springBoot para trabalhar controllers. O tipo do arquivo é Multipart.

A minha dúvida é , tem como eu fazer isso ? ou deveria enviar o arquivo primeiro e depois o restante dos dados.

Comment: Não é possível enviar um arquivo através do JSON, exceto se converte-lo para base64, por exemplo.

Comment: mesmo se eu mudar o atributo enctype da tag form para: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1):

Se o arquivo for pequeno (alguns KB) e sempre for um arquivo texto sem formatação (.txt) você pode converter o conteúdo para Base64 e enviar no *payload* do objeto JSON.

O lado negativo desse método é o esforço para converter o arquivo para Base64 no cliente e depois converter para texto novamente no servidor. Além disso, a string resultante em Base64 ficaria cerca de 1/3 maior que o arquivo original. Por esse motivo, eu só usaria esse método para arquivos de alguns KB e **sobre os quais eu tivesse o controle total da requisição no cliente**.

Caso você não tenha controle do que está sendo enviado, um cliente malicioso poderia enviar uma requisição com um arquivo de vários MB codificado em Base64 e causar problemas ao seu servidor.

Se você quiser uma solução mais elaborada, que atenda a qualquer tipo e tamanho de arquivo, sugiro que faça o cliente enviar duas requisições. Na primeira, você envia apenas os atributos. A entidade é criada e retorna o URL para o envio da imagem.

Exemplo da primeira requisição:

```
PUT /restapi/v1/clientes HTTP/1.1
Host: www.seuhost.com.br/

{
  "nomeCliente" : "Jean", 
  //Outros atributos 
}
```

Retorno com status 201 (criado):

```
{
  meta: {
  },
  data: {
    "urlArquivo": "http://www.seuhost2.com.br/apirest/v1/clientes/id/123456/arquivo"
  }
}
```

O cliente então usaria esse URL para enviar o arquivo.

Dessa forma, você pode criar controles específicos sobre o arquivo enviado. Pode inclusive determinar que todos os arquivos sejam enviados para um outro servidor, para não congestionar o servidor da aplicação original.

Comment: obrigado pela dica, eu imaginava que fosse por esse caminho mesmo. Vou direcionar inicialmente fazendo com base64 pois tenho certeza que meu arquivo é pequeno, porém o meu formato não é txt é binário.